# Issue looping through worksheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a debugging problem for homework in class and I made the changes I saw that were necessary but I am getting an error. It says `method or data member not found` for my code that is `shtCurrent.name` that is in the message box.

I have researched as much as possible but I cannot find an answer. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

```
Public Sub PrintWorksheets1()
    'declare variables and assign address to object variable
    Dim strPrint As String, wkbHours As Workbook, shtCurrent As Worksheets
    Set wkbHours = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_HW10_Ex9.xlsm")
    wkbHours.Activate
    'ask user if he or she wants to print the worksheet
    For Each shtCurrent In wkbHours.Worksheets
        strPrint = _
            MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent.Name & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
        If strPrint = vbYes Then        'if user wants to print
            shtCurrent.PrintPreview
        End If
    Next shtCurrent
End Sub
```

Comment: in the "for each" loop instead of the "shtCurrent.PrintPreview"?

Answer (score 4):

The `shtCurrent As Worksheets` should not be the worksheet**S** collection, just the worksheet object.

```
Dim strPrint As String, wkbHours As Workbook, shtCurrent As Worksheet
```

Comment: What is the difference in the two collections? The reason I put worksheetS is because it came up in a list of recommendations.

Comment: I just made the edit and that did run by the way, so thank you!

Comment: The [Worksheets](http://tinyurl.com/ngxc8t2) property is the collection of worksheets within a workbook. The [Worksheet Object](http://tinyurl.com/oqkcojt) refers to an individual worksheet. The latter has properties like `.Name`, `.cells` etc. By declaring `shtCurrent As Worksheets` you were essentially saying *for each All-Of-These-Worksheets in All-Of-These-Worksheets*. If declared as `shtCurrent As Worksheet` then you are saying *for each Worksheet in All-Of-These-Worksheets* which is what you wanted.