# Issue using "For" loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason my code is not working. I am getting "Error 91". I ran it fine with a "For each loop but this is not working for me.

It is telling me to debug at

```
strPrint = MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
```

but I cannot find anything wrong with it.

```
Public Sub PrintWorksheets2()

    'declare variables and assign address
    Dim strPrint As String, intCount As Integer, wkbHours As Workbook, shtCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim intSum As Integer, shtCount As Integer
    Set wkbHours = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_HW10_Ex9.xlsm")

    shtCount = wkbHours.Sheets.Count
    intSum = 0

    'ask user if he or she wants to print the worksheet
    For intCount = 1 To shtCount
        'shtCurrent = wkbHours
        intSum = intSum + intCount
        strPrint = MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
        If strPrint = vbYes Then        'if user wants to print
            shtCurrent.PrintPreview
        End If
    Next intCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Try declaring strPrint as variant instead of string.

Comment: Okay I will. Although, I declared it as a string in my "For Each" loop?

Comment: @bodjo, good catch. Even better would be `VbMsgBoxResult`.

Comment: @DougGlancy as the variable name and then variant as the data type?

Comment: You never assign (Set) shtCurrent = to a worksheet.  That will --> error 91.  Also, you probably want shtCurrent.Name in your MsgBox

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I do not want to assign it to one specific worksheet but rather pull the name of each worksheet in sequential order.

Comment: Then you need to assign to each worksheet in sequential order.  If you never assign it to anything, you **will** get that error. Something like: Set shtCurrent = Worksheets(intCount) at the beginning of your loop.

Comment: Ah I see now. That makes sense. Then how come i did not ever assign it to each worksheet in my "For Each" example but it worked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723119/issue-looping-through-worksheets-in-a-workbook

Comment: Austin, no, `vbMsgBoxResult` is a data type. You can then check if it returns, `VbYes`, `vbCancel`, etc.

Comment: @AustinColaizzi In that code, you implicitly assign it in the *For Each shtCurrent In wkbHours.Worksheets* statement.  That is very different from what you are doing in this code here.

Comment: @AustinColaizzi your `For Each` loop prints the `shtCurrent.Name` *name* property of the worksheet. This code tries to print `shtCurrent`, and that's not a `String`, it's an object, hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

`shtCurrent` is a `Worksheet` object. Try concatenating its `Name` property (which is a `String`) into your msgbox prompt:

```
strPrint = MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent.Name & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
```

Now `strPrint` is declared as a `String`:

```
Dim strPrint As String
```

And `MsgBox` will return a `vbMsgBoxResult` enum value - you're making VBA do lots of useless implicit type conversions here, why not declare it as the type it's returned as?

```
Dim strPrint As vbMsgBoxResult
```

And now you see why prefixing `str` to variable names (aka Hungarian notation) is bad.

---

That only addresses part of the issue. When you had a `For Each` loop, each iteration assigned a value to an object variable that represented the current iteration's worksheet. In this code with a `For` loop, you have a `shtCurrent` worksheet object, but it's not assigned; you're incrementing a counter, but that's all you're doing. As was hinted in the comments, you also need to `Set` the reference for the `shtCurrent` object inside the loop, *before* you use it - otherwise your code will blow up with an "object variable not set" error.

Your `For` loop iterates worksheet indices, so you can assign `shtCurrent` to an item in the `Worksheets` collection:

```
Set shtCurrent = Worksheets(intCount)
```

Do that before anything else inside the body of the `For` loop, and you should be good to go.

Now that's all nice, but when you're iterating objects, it's often better to use a `For Each` loop instead of a `For` loop. `For` loops are good for iterating *arrays*; `For Each` loops are good for iterating *collections* - I'd use a `For Each` loop here.

Comment: If we declare as Dim strPrint As String and if we check msgbox result like this If strPrint = vbYes Then. It is still inappropriate way and as you said it will make VBA to do implicit type conversion for this statement too?

Comment: @PareshJadhav `vbYes` is a member of the `VbMsgBoxResult` enum type, and has an underlying `Integer` value of `6` - in the case you describe, when the user clicks the "Yes" button, the result of the `MsgBox` call stored in `strPrint` will be converted to `"6"` so as to store the result in the allocated `String` variable, and VB will implicitly convert `vbYes` to its `"6"` string representation before it compares it to `strPrint` in the `if strPrint = vbYes` expression... so yes.

Comment: Thanks RetailCoder for explanation. One last doubt. If we declare variable as VbMsgBoxResult then implicit conversion is required or not?

Comment: By declaring `strPrint As VbMsgBoxResult`, you're storing the result of the `MsgBox` call in a `VbMsgBoxResult` variable, that will have an underlying value of `6` when the user clicks the "Yes" button; when you compare if to `vbYes` in the `if strPrint = vbYes` expression, VBA doesn't need to convert anything to perform the comparison, it just evalues `If 6 = 6 Then` and no string is ever involved; no string is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
'declare variables and assign address
Dim strPrint As String, intCount As Integer, wkbHours As Workbook, shtCurrent As Worksheet
Dim intSum As Integer, shtCount As Integer
Dim oResult
Set wkbHours = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_HW10_Ex9.xlsm")

shtCount = wkbHours.Sheets.Count
intSum = 0

'ask user if he or she wants to print the worksheet
For intCount = 1 To shtCount
    'shtCurrent = wkbHours
    intSum = intSum + intCount
    oResult = MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
    If oResult = vbYes Then        'if user wants to print
        shtCurrent.PrintPreview
    End If
Next intCount
```

Comment: I got error 91 still "Object variable or with block variable not set". It doesn't like the line "vbResult = MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation"

Comment: I haven't tested the code. But i changed vbResult to oResult. Looks like shtCurrent is the one causing the error as mentioned by @Ron.

Comment: I will give that a go. What should the data type be, variant?